Philosophy of cyclic functions for positional encoding
I have read several pages, e.g. this, about what is positional encoding and why the original authors came up with the idea of using a sin/cos functions. However, still I have some questions about the philosophy of using such weird functions, which I haven't found the answers yet. Briefly, my questions are:
1- Given a sentence where words have logical indices from 0 to n, why a positional encoder expands the "order definition" to a vector? I understand the transformer parallel logic needs to know the order of the words, but why each word should have a vector? In that case, what does PE[0] really means compared to PE[511]?  Does that imply we always see large values in PE[0] compared to PE[511], e.g. 0.89 vs 0.03?
2- Thinking about creating a novel order definition, why a cyclic definition is needed? I know that 0...n ordering and [0,1] floating point ordering are not efficient. But how one can jump from linear ordering idea to a cyclic order?
